# Sending more GTM event data without duplicating Tags

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I collect video tracking data to data layer and I would like send all the data as a part of the same event.

```
    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'video',
        'EventCategory': 'HTML5 Video',
        'EventAction': VideoProgressWatched,
        'EventLabel': videoLink,
        'EventContributor': videoContributor,
        'EventVideoCategory': videoCategory,
        'EventVideoDuration': videoDuration
    });
```

I tried splitting this into few different Tags that are triggered by the same triggers.

**Tag 1:**

Event Category: `{{EventCategory}}`,

Event Action: `{{EventAction}}`,

Event Label: **`{{EventLabel}}`**

**Tag 2:**

Event Category: `{{EventCategory}}`,

Event Action: `{{EventAction}}`,

Event Label: **`{{EventContributor}}`**

**Tag 3:**

Event Category: `{{EventCategory}}`,

Event Action: `{{EventAction}}`,

Event Label: **`{{EventVideoCategory}}`**

But I somehow doubt this is the right way to do it. What would be the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider sending the additional data as hit-scoped custom dimensions, then on the GA side defining those Custom dimensions as things like "Event Contributor" etc.